# Equivalent of TX index=1 in Bitcoin

Tags: blockchain, database, blockchain-data

I believe that the Monero blockchain database is already the equivalent of running Bitcoin core with txindex set to 1. Is this correct?

Are there any options to increase the TX or other metadata stored in the blockchain database, or is everything possible already being stored and indexed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Blocks, txs, outputs, and spent keys are already indexed. What else is there? The complete DB schema is here https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp#L148

Comment: That was kind of my question re: what else is there :)